# No module named 'bluetooth' when using python PyBluez library

Tags: python, bluetooth, pycharm, pybluez

I installed PyBluez on my machine. I checked the interpreter setting it shows that PyBluez is there. But when i run the line `import bluetooth` i get the error

> No module named 'bluetooth'

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this. I tried `import PyBluez` and it did not work either. Here's the image of the setting and the error
[image]

Comment: Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting it as the "best answer". Doing that will acknowledge the answer and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community. You receive points each time you close out a question.

Answer (score 1):

In the image you've uploaded, you're showing that in the CMD, the "correct" library is installed, but you're running the project from Pycharm's terminal, and looking closely, I can see you're using a virtual environment in Pycharm, but it doesn't see to be activated on the CMD.

So, there are lots of ways of achieving this.

##### Pycharm

1. Check that venv is activated (you should see **(venv)** on top)
2. Run **pip freeze** to check if all libraries are correctly installed
3. Run the project again

##### CMD/ some terminal

1. Install/activate a **venv**

```
python -m venv venv
```

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

```
pip install <whatever you need>
```

I highly recommend using an external terminal and not to run projects from the IDE + using always a venv